# Getting closeEvent when exiting the application

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5

I'm trying to make a small python programs which is able to have several windows.  The issue is when I try to implement a menu entry to quit the programs, closing all the windows at once.  I've tried to use `qApp.close()` and `qApp.exit()` but if those allow to effectively quit the program, there is no close events generated for the windows still opened, which prevent me to save modified data or to prevent leaving the application.  What's the best practice for that?  I could understand not being able to cancel the exit process, but being able to propose to save modified data is something I really want.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

opened_windows = set()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_actions()
        opened_windows.add(self)

    def closeEvent(self, ev):
        if QMessageBox.question(self, 'Closing', 'Really close?') == QMessageBox.Yes:
            ev.accept()
            opened_windows.remove(self)
        else:
            ev.ignore()

    def create_action(self, action_callback, menu, action_name):
        action = QAction(action_name, self)
        action.triggered.connect(action_callback)
        menu.addAction(action)

    def create_actions(self):
        _file_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&File')
        self.create_action(self.on_new, _file_menu, '&New')
        _file_menu.addSeparator()
        self.create_action(self.on_close, _file_menu, '&Close')
        self.create_action(self.on_quit, _file_menu, '&Quit')
        self.create_action(self.on_exit, _file_menu, '&Exit')

    def on_new(self):
        win = MainWindow()
        win.show()

    def on_close(self):
        self.close()

    def on_quit(self):
        qApp.quit()

    def on_exit(self):
        qApp.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    status = app.exec()
    print(len(opened_windows), ' window(s) opened')
    print('status = ', status)
    sys.exit(status)
```

Currently I'm modifying `on_close` and `on_exit` like this:

```py
    def on_exit(self):
        for w in opened_windows.copy():
            w.on_close()
        if len(opened_windows) == 0:
            qApp.exit(1)
```

but I wonder if I'm missing a better way which would not force me to maintain a set of opened windows.

Comment: Assuming `actClose : QAction` is the _menu entry to quit the programs_, connect `actClose::triggered` to `MainWindow::close` and there you have your `closeEvent`

Comment: @scopchanov, either I don't understand what you mean, or it won't work when there are several windows opened.

Comment: A couple of things: first, change `self.create_action(self.on_exit, _file_menu, '&Exit')` to `self.create_action(self.close, _file_menu, '&Exit')`. Second, change `win = MainWindow() win.show()` to `win = MainWindow(self)` and try again.

Comment: Sorry, leave `win.show`. Otherwise it should work. I've just tested it and I get as many close events, as the created main windows.

Comment: @scopchanov If I do that, I've a main window tree.  I can close them all from the root one, but not from another one.

Comment: Well, the __main__ window isn't call so for no reason. Its like having several prime ministers. Whatever concept of government you might preffer, you have to admit, that a second prime minister does not make sence - should be either prime, or second, or third... Anyway, if you really insist on using many main windows and you want them all closed if any of them is closed, take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: @scopchanov I'm not sure why you think my request strange. That's the behavior of most applications. I've just tried with Outlook, PyCharm, Chrome and Emacs. They all have the possibility to open several top windows, to close them individually and to exit the application closing all the opened windows. (Outlook admittedly is strange, there is at least two types of top level windows which behave differently in that respect and you have to play with desktops to be able to open several main windows).

Comment: In one Qt application you have one event loop (started by `app.exec()`), unless you create another one, which you do not, or at least it seems so looking at the code you have provided. I would like to leave that aside though and concentrate on the problem with closing multiple windows. Does the addition to my answer not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I wonder how I missed it before.  There is the [QApplication::closeAllWindows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#closeAllWindows) slot which does exactly what I want and whose example is a binding to exit.

---

There is a way to propose to save modified data on `quit` and `exit`, the signal `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit`.

Note that although the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) says that user interaction is not possible, at least with PyQt5 I could use a QMessageBox without apparent issues.

Comment: There is a video of a guy, using his car's modifiied wheel as a lathe to turn wooden pieces. Apparently it works... somehow. My point is, use the library as intended, if you want to make an easily maintainable software, free from nasty surprises.

Comment: @scopchanov, well there is a reason for which I didn't accept my answer.  It provides a partial and unsatisfying answer.  I still prefer maintaining a set of opened windows and iterating on it when asked to exit.

Comment: _I still prefer maintaining a set of opened windows and iterating on it_ Again I have to opose you, finding such a strategy unncecessary, to say the least. Qt has a parent-child mechanism build in, which takes care of the corresponding relationships and there is no need to duplicate it, or at least not in this case. I suggest you to implement it the way I've added to my answer (points 2 and 3). I strongly believe that this is the intended way of using the library to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

It is important to understand, that the app and the main window are related, but are not the same thing. So, when you want to close the program, don't bother closing the app. Close the main window instead. From the documentation of [QCloseEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcloseevent.html) :

> Close events are sent to widgets that the user wants to close, usually by choosing "Close" from the window menu, or by clicking the X title bar button. They are also sent when you call QWidget::close() to close a widget programmatically.

## Solution

1. Connect your exit-action's `triggered` signal to the `close` slot of your `MainWindow`. In your case, instead of:

   ```
   self.create_action(self.on_exit, _file_menu, '&Exit')
   ```

   write:

   ```
   self.create_action(self.close, _file_menu, '&Exit').
   ```
2. Define in `MainWindow` a signal `closed` and emit it from your implementation of the `closedEvent`, e.g. in the place of `opened_windows.remove(self)`
3. In `on_new` connect `win.closed` to `self.close`

## Example

Here is how I suggest you to change your code in order to implement the proposed solution:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    closed = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_actions()

    def closeEvent(self, ev):
        if QMessageBox.question(self, 'Closing', 'Really close?') == QMessageBox.Yes:
            ev.accept()
            self.closed.emit()
        else:
            ev.ignore()

    def create_action(self, action_callback, menu, action_name):
        action = QAction(action_name, self)
        action.triggered.connect(action_callback)
        menu.addAction(action)

    def create_actions(self):
        _file_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&File')
        self.create_action(self.on_new, _file_menu, '&New')
        _file_menu.addSeparator()
        self.create_action(self.close, _file_menu, '&Exit')

    def on_new(self):
        win = MainWindow()
        win.show()
        win.closed.connect(self.close)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    status = app.exec()
    print('status = ', status)
    sys.exit(status)
```